# RTOS μC/OS-II not running as expected

Tags: rtos

I'm using ST STM32F101xB and μC/OS-II, I was having external clock (HSE) on old board and it's running fine. We wanted to use internal clock (HSI) on new board, however, the RTOS (Appmaintask()) doesn't run using internal clock, i have changed my code as below, any idea what's wrong with the change:

```
void  BSP_Init (void)
{
    RCC_DeInit();
    //RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
    //RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp();

    RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1);
    RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div1);   // APB2 clock divide by 1 => 64MHz
    RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);   // APB1 clock divide by 2 => 32MHz

    FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);
    FLASH_PrefetchBufferCmd(FLASH_PrefetchBuffer_Enable);
    //RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSE_Div1, RCC_PLLMul_8); // 64MHz
    RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSI_Div2, RCC_PLLMul_8); 
    RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);

    RCC_LSEConfig(RCC_LSE_OFF);

    while (RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY) == RESET) {
        ;
    }

    RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);

    while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != 0x08) {
        ;
    }

    //Set the Vector Table base location at 0x08000000
    //NVIC_SetVectorTable(NVIC_VectTab_FLASH, 0x0);

    // Need to finalize and arange priority for each interrupts in future,
    // So that 1 interrupt wont blocks another interrupt.
    NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_3);
}


void main()
{
  INT8U   err;

  cpuObj = new Cstm32f10x();

  BSP_Init();

  BSP_IntDisAll();         /* Disable all ints until we are ready to accept them.  */

  OSInit();

  err = OSTaskCreateExt (AppMainTask,
                     (void *)0,
                     (OS_STK *)&AppMainTaskStk[APP_MAIN_TASK_STK_SIZE-1],
                     APP_MAIN_TASK_PRIO,
                     APP_MAIN_TASK_ID,
                     (OS_STK *)&AppMainTaskStk[0],
                     APP_MAIN_TASK_STK_SIZE,
                     (void *)0,
                     OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CHK | OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CLR);

  OSStart();                    // Start multitasking (i.e. give control to uC/OS-II)
}

void  AppMainTask (void *p_arg)
{ 
  OS_CPU_SysTickInit();
  while(TRUE)
  {
    OSTimeDly(1);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you just include the relevant code? (eg tell us the bit you changed perhaps)? Also - you need to ell us what is wrong with the change? what did you see happen? what did you expect to see happen?

Comment: Should first check the bahaviour after frequencies are switched. Up to what code the CPU is still running and what happens to it next?

Comment: My problem is after OSstart(), Appmaintask() doesn't get called.

Comment: Having taken the trouble to capture the return from `OSTaskCreateExt`, you might want to test it.  Your code comments are suspicious - the STM32F101 runs only up to 36MHz.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up of the PLL is normally performed in the CMSIS start-up code provided by ST/ARM.  This code executes as part of the runtime environment start-up *before* `main()` is called.  I recommend that you use this code for chip initialisation since static data initialisation and static object constructors run *before* `main()` and will be running before possibly critical initialisation.

The CMSIS with Cortex-M3 core and STM32F1xx specific device support is included in the [STM32 Standard Peripheral Library](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257890). The file that actually does the work is system_stm32f10x.c.  Other functions you are performing in `BSP_Init()` such as flash latency are also dealt with by the CMSIS start-up code.  Even if you customise this code, I strongly recommend that you use this method of *early* environment initialisation.

Another possibility is to use the [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1533/PF259242) utility to generate configuration code.  This appears to be a replacement for the apparently now unavailable [STM32 MicroXplorer](http://www.stmicroelectronics.com.cn/st-web-ui/static/active/cn/resource/technical/document/release_note/DM00030412.pdf) utility.